# Preventing a list box from doubling its contents

Tags: c#, visual-studio, listbox

[Image of my form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gWy4.png)

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional, using a windows forms app (.NET Framework) in C#.  I have a list box that displays the entered cost for 18 credits and adds them all together when you click a calculate button, what I want to do is make it so you can only display the 18 credits once, so if someone clicks on the calculate button twice it wont display the information twice.
Here's my code

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Create a double for the amount entered for tuition
    double dblTuition;


    //Validate the cost
    if (double.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out dblTuition))
    {
        //Validate the cost textbox contol
        if (double.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out dblTuition))
        {

            //Constant for the maximum number 
            const int MAX_VALUE = 18;

            dblTuition.ToString("c");

            //display the tuition
            for (int x = 1; x <= MAX_VALUE; x++)
            {
                lstTuition.Items.Add(x + " Credits ~" + " " + (x * dblTuition).ToString("c"));
            }

        }
        if (dblTuition < 0)
        {
            //Display an error message for the cost textbox
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input, Cost Needs to be Greater than Zero.");

            //Set the cost to zero
            txtCost.Text = string.Empty;

            //set focus to cost
            txtCost.Focus();
            txtCost.SelectAll();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Display an error message for the Cost textbox
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for Cost.");

        //Set the cost to zero
        txtCost.Text = string.Empty;

        txtCost.Focus();
        txtCost.SelectAll();
    }

    txtCost.Focus();
    txtCost.SelectAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear the listbox before adding new items

```
lstTuition.Items.Clear();
for (int x = 1; x <= MAX_VALUE; x++)
{
    lstTuition.Items.Add(x + " Credits ~" + " " + (x * dblTuition).ToString("c"));
}
```

Also, your code can be simplified.

- `dblTuition.ToString("c");` is superfluous and does nothing, since the formatted value is not assigned to any variable.
- `txtCost.Focus(); txtCost.SelectAll();` is done at the end anyway and can be dropped inside the `if` and `else`.
- The declaration of `dblTuition` can inlined in the `out` expression.
- You are parsing `txtCost.Text` twice and the if statement logic is wrong.
- String interpolation can be used to simplify the string creation.
- Use a speaking name for the constant instead of adding a comment. It is always better to use speaking names rahter than bad names + comment.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Validate the cost
    if (Double.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out double dblTuition)) {
        if (dblTuition > 0) {
            const int NumberOfCreditsToDisplay = 18;

            //display the tuition
            lstTuition.Items.Clear();
            for (int x = 1; x <= NumberOfCreditsToDisplay; x++) {
                lstTuition.Items.Add($"{x} Credits ~ {x * dblTuition:c}");
            }
        } else {
            //Display an error message for the cost textbox
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Input, Cost Needs to be Greater than Zero.");

            //Set the cost to zero
            txtCost.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    } else {
        //Display an error message for the Cost textbox
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input for Cost.");

        //Set the cost to zero
        txtCost.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    txtCost.Focus();
    txtCost.SelectAll();
}
```

Comments above a piece of code are often a hint that this code could be extracted to another method (whose name replaces the comment) which often leads to more readable and more maintainable code.

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Validate the cost
    if (Double.TryParse(txtCost.Text, out double dblTuition)) {
        if (dblTuition > 0) {
            DisplayTheTuition(dblTuition);
        } else {
            DisplayMessageAndResetCost("Invalid input, Cost needs to be greater than zero.");
        }
    } else {
        DisplayMessageAndResetCost("Invalid input for Cost.");
    }
    txtCost.Focus();
    txtCost.SelectAll();
}

private void DisplayTheTuition(double dblTuition)
{
    const int NumberOfCreditsToDisplay = 18;
    lstTuition.Items.Clear();
    for (int x = 1; x <= NumberOfCreditsToDisplay; x++) {
        lstTuition.Items.Add($"{x} Credits ~ {x * dblTuition:c}");
    }
}

private void DisplayMessageAndResetCost(string message)
{
    MessageBox.Show(message);
    txtCost.Text = String.Empty;
}
```